# Updating a MongoDB collection with PUT request and updateOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Problem: The data in collection is not updating. I first tried doing User.update and Group.update to update their array, which gave me a deprecation messaged and did updateOne instead. The code seems to be running but I don't understand why the data is not updating. Whatever I sent from the front end gets processed in the backend. The backend "auth" is a JWT token verification, which passes. I thought about using a POST request, but I already have a POST request for this route.

Goal: When pressing the "JoinButton", update the 'user' array in Group Schema, and $push in the current user's name

```
BACKEND EXPRESS ROUTER to "/groups"
router.put("/", auth, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        await User.updateOne(
            {'profile.$.username': req.body.id}, 
            {$addToSet: {'profile.$.groups':req.body.groupId} })
        await Group.updateOne(
            {name: req.body.groupID}, 
            {$addToSet: {users : req.body.id} })
        // below code is just to see if it updated
        let user = await User.find({'profile.username': req.body.id})
        console.log("user: ", user)
        let group = await Group.find({name: req.body.groupId})
        console.log("group: ", group)
        res.status(200).json({user, group})
    } catch {
        res.status(500).json({failure:"PUT request failed"})

    }
})
```

```
GROUP SCHEMA
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   skills: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   description: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   curCap: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   maxCap: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   users: {
       type: [String],
       required: true
   }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("group", GroupSchema)


USER SCHEMA (in a separate file)
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    profile: {
        username: {
            type: String, 
            required: true
        },
        groups: [String]
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema)
```

```
FRONTEND FETCH REQUEST
const JoinButton = ({token, id, groupId}) => {
    const handleJoin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!token && !id) {
            alert("You must log in to join a group")
        } else {
            fetch ("http://localhost:5000/groups", {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({id, groupId})
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("data", data)
                    return data
                })
                .catch(err=>{
                    console.error("error: ", err)
                })
        }
    }
    // return the code for JoinButton component
}
export default JoinButton
```

Comment: it should be` await User.updateOne({'profile.username': req.body.id}, {$addToSet: {'profile.groups' : req.body.id} })`

but there is no  `profile.groups` in user schema

Comment: ah my bad, it's in my code, but I missed it when I was copy pasting

Comment: it works for User, but not for Group.. that's weird..

Comment: is groupId name of group?

Comment: yessir. the Group.find works file, and I use that same requirement to find the name of the group to check if it's locating the correct group

Comment: ah found my mistake... spelling error lmao thank you so much for your time

Answer (score -1):

Use `FindONeandUpdate()` instead of `upadateOne()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).